# python 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict' (2.7.6)

Tags: python, collections, sys.path

I am new to Python. I tried to do the following:

```
    $ python 
    Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import collections
    >>> d=collections.OrderedDict()
```

and I got the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'
```

I read some of the similar problems reported on the forum. But I am not sure why I still have the same problem as I am using 2.7.6 version. 
Here is the path information:

```
    >>> sys.path
    ['', '/Users/currentuser/research/prog/python/divintopython','/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin','/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac','/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-criptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload','/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

I am wondering if the problem is related to the sys.path setting. As it is automatically generated.

Thank you very much for any kind feedback!

Comment: Your path includes the old 2.6 directories. Dunno why.

Comment: Yes. I installed the later version: 2.7.6, but the old version is still there. Could you please let me know how to get rid of that? Thanks!

Comment: I am unfortunately not qualified to handle this problem. It's probably simple (wiping the PYTHONPATH environment variable would be my guess), but I don't know enough about this kind of configuration to properly advise you.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your kind suggestions. Unfortunately, after added PATHONPATH variable in the ~/.bash_profile file with only the 2.7.6 related directories. After I restart python, I still got the old version.

Comment: What does `print collections.__file__` says?

Comment: >>> print collections.__file__ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/collections.py

Comment: @ddz. Did you really add `PATHONPATH`, or is that just a typo in your comment?

Comment: Hi ekhumoro, my fault should be PATHONPATH. Problem solved, thanks :-)